# Using promises with $routeProvider to create resolve variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have 3 factory functions that I would like to chain together to be used in a resolve stanza of a route:

1st function is a simple REST call to $http:

```
app.factory('services', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var serviceBase = 'services/';
    var obj = {};
    obj.getSelect = function (db, table, columns, keys) {
        return $http.post(serviceBase + 'getSelect', {
            selectDB: db,
            selectTable: table,
            selectColumn: columns,
            selectKeys: keys
        }).then(function (results) {
            return results;
        });
    };

    // more objects follow
}
```

It is used by the next function that simply calls services.getSelect to retrieve some records:

```
app.factory('myFunctions', ['services', '$q',  function (services, $q) {    
    return {
        fGetData: function () {
            services.getSelect(
                'myDB',       // DB
                'tableInDB',  // Table
                "*",                // Columns
                ""                  // Keys
            ).then(
                function (retObj) {
                    return $q.all (retObj);
                    console.log('myFunctions.fGetData', retObj);
                }
            )
        }
    }
}]);
```

The last function calls myFunctions.fGetData.  Its purpose is to return values to the resolve stanza:

```
app.factory("getInitData",['myFunctions','$q', function (myFunctions, $q) {
    return function () {
        var initData = myFunctions.fGetData();

        return $q.all( {initData: results} ).then(function (results) {
            return {
                initDataReturn: results
            };
            console.log('getInitData', results);
        });
    }
}]);
```

and finally the resolve stanza:

```
app.config( ['$routeProvider', 'myConst', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(myConst.adminButtonURL, {
        templateUrl: '/myTemplateURL',
        controller: myControler,
        resolve: {
                initDataObj: function(getInitData){
                    return getInitData();
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

In the controller the initDataObj is returned:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, nitDataObj {

    $scope.surveyGroup = initDataObj.initData;

});
```

The console logs always show that 'getInitdata' always fires first and the return is a null object.

The function myFunctions.fGetData always fires first and the correct data is returned.

To miss-quote a song from He Haw: "I've searched the world over and I thought I'd find the answer (`true love` is lyric)", but while there have been very interesting bits of clues including

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/promises-in-angular-js/ &
http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/

nothing has had the complete answer.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

ok i think in part this has to do with the way you are using $q

$q.all take an array or an object containing promises
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

in your services factory you are resolving the promise and then returning the results

and then in myFunctions you are taking the returned value and trying to give it to $q.all which doesnt accept what you're giving it

looks like your wanting to keep sending a promise back from each factory you could do something like

```
app.factory('services', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var serviceBase = 'services/';
    var obj = {};
    obj.getSelect = function (db, table, columns, keys) {
        return $http.post(serviceBase + 'getSelect', {
            selectDB: db,
            selectTable: table,
            selectColumn: columns,
            selectKeys: keys
        });
    };

    // more objects follow
}

app.factory("myFunctions", ["$q", "services", function($q, services){
    return {
        fGetData: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            services.getSelect()
                .success(function(results){
                    // do something with the data
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory("getInitData",['myFunctions', function (myFunctions) {
    return function () {
        myFunctions.fGetData()
            .then(function(data){
                // do something with the data
            });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: on the right track but no need to create new promise in `fGetData` since `services.getSelect` already returns a `$http` promise. Is considered an anti pattern

Comment: Yep.   1) remove the '.then' block from the 'services' factory making the function getSelect a function with a promise (with the 'then', the promise objects are removed.. 2) use the deferred method.  - Thanks.

Comment: but there would need to be a new promise created if the data needed to be resolved and manipulated before passing it on to getInitData.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do.  The middle function (fGetData) will be used in other controllers with other views and in this case, used to seed the controller prior to its creation.